# My kivy program always rotate 180 degree and become upside down

Tags: python, kivy

Whenever I try to run any kivy program even a simple 'HelloWorld' program the program runs but it become upside down and rotates 180 degree automatically. I try reinstalling each and every deps of kivy but not fixed the problem. Please help me with that.

Even a simple hello world program also become upside down.

```
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.label import Label

class Myapp(App):

    def build(self):

        return Label(text='Helloworld !!')

if __name__=='__main__':

    Myapp().run()
```

expected --->  `Helloworld !!`

actual ----->  Helloworld !! (but rotates 180 degree automatically)

Comment: Press F1 to access the Kivy settings, and check what the rotation value is set to.

Comment: wow it works...!
thank u so much @Fabich